# Avast blocks infection on a particular Stack Overflow CV profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Just wanted to report that AVAST blocked an infection on the following profile:

`http://stackoverflow.com/cv/aram`

This is not my profile, of course. Here are the screenshots of the Avast notice:
[image]

It does not happen on other CVs. I submitted this through the contact form, but I got a response saying to post it here instead.

Comment: Well, I put it in the title, as well as the first paragraph :) I'll add a notice in bold.

Comment: Isn't this Avast's problem for being silly?

Comment: Eset NOD32 reports JS/Iframe.NB trojan

Comment: @cat Perhaps Avast's fault, but someone else's problem?

Comment: @Alex OP's for using (bad) antivirus? I don't see how it's SO's

Comment: @cat They have a problem if the anti-virus they're using is rubbish, yes?

Comment: @Alex Yes, exactly

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's almost certainly triggering on the content of this post, which is embedded in the CV as a recent answer:

[What is this mystery code that was hacked onto my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123737/what-is-this-mystery-code-that-was-hacked-onto-my-site/9123799#9123799)

As cat mentioned in a comment, this is indeed "Avast being silly". While the post does contain some malicious code, the code is present as plain text, and poses no threat.

Comment: Silly indeed. That iframe code isn't even exactly being served as plain text, it's being served HTML encoded. `&lt;iframe src="...` would never make an iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and looking into this!

Comment: Same way, AVG Internet Security, is also being silly and blocking me from opening linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123737/what-is-this-mystery-code-that-was-hacked-onto-my-site/9123799#9123799